# nodejs, krakenjs, mongoose, dustjs - Deleting documents on button click

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dust.js, kraken.js

I have a button in a view in a user's profile. When the button is pressed, all the user's messages (stored as individual documents) should be deleted.

The view is located at `/profile`. I have access to the `user` object, and can get all of the user's messages.

I'm not really sure where and how I should be implementing the button's listener. Should it be in the controller (`/controllers/profile.js`) somewhere, in the model (`/models/profile.js`), or in the view (`/public/templates/profile.dust`)?

Just for reference, here is the code that I think *should* work to delete all the appropriate messages:

`Messages.find({ ref: user.ref }).remove().exec();`

where `ref` is how I keep track of which user a Message belongs to. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should **not** be on the controller since controllers are on the server side already. It's purpose is to facilitate endpoints, routing and other back-end stuff. It should **not** be on the model, as per practice, model should just be plain objects that act as a transport object. I guess the best option is on the dust page, front-end javascript would trigger/call your end-point in the controller to process/facilitate the logic.

For cleaner implementation we use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) on our frontend, you could check it out.